# How to get a channel name Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Im making a bot using discord.py and I am trying to get the channel name to confirm where to send the embed like:

Where do you want the Embed to be sent?

1 - #general

2 - different channel

Here is the code I tried to use:

```
channel = client.get_channel(ctx.author)
```

I get this error

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'context' object has no attribute 'text_channel'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a [brief glance at the docs would have told you](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.channel) you can get a channel object from the context object by doing

```py
channel = ctx.channel
```

You can do a few different things with that like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def make_embed(ctx, embed_content, channel : discord.Channel):
    # create your embed here
    await ctx.send(f"Did you mean to send the embed to {ctx.channel.name} or {channel.name}?")
```

You'll note that you can also pass a channel object in the command call like I demonstrated above.

Answer (score 1):

`clint.get_chanel` can be uses by id of the channel.

```
channel = client.get_channel(123456789123456789)
await channel.send("message")
```

If you want to get channel with name, use `discord.utils`

```
channels = [c for g in client.guilds for c in g.text_channels] #getting all the text channels bot can see
channel = discord.utils.get(channels, name="general")
```

Also, if you have the guild, you can replace `channels` with `guild.text_channels` or `guild.voice_channels` e.t.c.